# Multiply grouped columns in pandas dataframe based on condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Consider a pandas dataframe `X`:

```
   s1  s2  l  X_ikl
0   1   2  1      0
1   1   3  1      0
2   2   1  1      1
3   2   3  1      8
4   2   3  2      2
5   2   3  3      4
6   3   4  1      1
7   3   4  2      1
8   3   5  1      2
9   3   5  2     10
```

I wanna multiply each `X_ikl` and then sum the results that has same column values `(s1,s2)`, such that it doesn't multiply with itself. If `(s1,s2)` only occur one time, then the value should be 0. The `l` column is used to index each pair of `(s1,s2)`. I need a relative efficient method (not `for loops` etc.) since the real dataframe is large.

In the above example, for each pair of `(s1,s2)` the calculations should be as follows

```
(1,2): 0
(1,3): 0
(2,1): 0
(2,3): 8*2 + 8*4 + 2*4 = 56
(3,4): 1*1 = 1
(2,5): 2*10 = 20
```

I tried to use

```
df.groupby(["s1","s2"]).apply(lambda x : np.sum(x["X_ikl"]*x["X_ikl"]))
```

but this results in each `X_ikl` grouped by `(s1,s2)` to multiply with itself, then sum, and nothing else. It basically does the opposite of what I need.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: why should `(2,1)` result to `0` ?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Since it only appear once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution:

```
from itertools import combinations

(df.groupby(['s1', 's2']).agg(
    {'X_ikl': lambda g: sum([x*y for x, y in combinations(g, 2)])}))
```

Output:

```
       X_ikl
s1 s2       
1  2       0
   3       0
2  1       0
   3      56
3  4       1
   5      20
```

Comment: Another way: `df.groupby(['s1', 's2'])['X_ikl'].agg(lambda g: sum(map(math.prod, combinations(g, 2))))`

Comment: Beautiful way, @mozway, as is your prerogative. Thanks!

Comment: just for fun, I think the list comprehension is more efficient ;)